# Best practise for data dump 'entry point' in DB processing chain - PostgreSQL

Tags: database-design, table, postgresql-10

I need to implement a process chain to transform and analyze potentially large sets of data, inserted both programmatically and manually (e.g. CSVs). In either way, the input data is standardized in terms of columns and datatypes. New data-sets are added regularly.

Once inserted, however, the data needs to be transformed and aggregated (spatially -> PostGIS) into different table structures (columns & datatypes) to then be analyzed extensively and distributed among several related tables where they will be stored (appended) as results. The initially inserted data will be obsolete once processed.

l need to define an 'entry point' to this process chain, and I am not sure which way to go; I intend to have users generally to not work on the base relations themselves (thus working on *Views*, while 'working on' generally refers to select and export), and I'd like to not have an 'empty' (truncated each time) physical table sitting in the DB for this if not necessary.

The 'entry point' should ideally be accessible via simple `INSERT` or `COPY`/`\copy` commands; I could possibly set up *fdw* connections to directly query the data without an 'entry point', but I'm not sure how I could make that available universally and mostly automated (I don't want users to need to set up the *fdw* server connection each time; if this can be automated, feel free to add solutions accordingly).

**How would I define an 'entry point' to dump data for further (automated) processing, where the input data structure differs substantially from the subsequent tables in the chain and has to be deleted after import or is only transitional?**

Comment: I do realize that this might better be handled externally/application-wise, but I am bound to do it this way.